# Connecting to Salesforce in Tableau

Tags: salesforce, tableau-api

While connecting with Sales force in Tableau, what is the best way to connect to multiple data sources from sales force in tableau (for example connecting Accounts , opportunities & products from sales force) ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on what you're trying to achieve. You have basically two options, join tables, or extract each one individually:

1) Join tables. This is very useful when you want to use information across tables in the same worksheet. For instance, If you have in your Accounts table and field that connects to products (for instance, the last product the client buy) through a key field (like product id), and you wish to analyze some product field across accounts, it's better to have joined table.
To do this, you need to use Multiple Tables option.
Downside is that this can generate a query that is too large for SF API to handle. I'm not sure if that was fixed yet, but when I tried to connect to a database, the connection would suddenly terminate and I would get no extract. Tableau support responded that this was a due to this SF API limitation (that can totally be overcome by breaking the queries, but I don't know if this has been fixed yet)

2) Extract one table at a time. Use this if you don't need to cross tables, basically. So there's no point in joining the tables. If you're going to analyze data of each table individually (one per worksheet), then go for this.
TO use this, use Single Table or Standard option
Downside is that Tableau data blending (if you come to need) is way more inefficient than working with a joined table.

Another important point is that Tableau does not allow Custom SQL for SF connection, which would be very helpful, especially when I don't need the full table, just a part of it.

Those limitations (query limit of SF API and no Custom SQL available by Tableau) made me use another solution to connect to SF. I use SF API using Pyhton, and export data to a tde using Tableau API (also with Python).

UPDATE:

For SF API, relate to https://github.com/idbentley/pyforce and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyforce/1.1dev

Also http://tomhayden3.com/2013/08/04/salesforce-python/ brings very good examples on how to use the package (especially querying more than 500 values, that is not obvious)

I also recommend using pandas for dataframe manipulation, though it's not mandatory. http://pandas.pydata.org/

For Tableau API, http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/extract-api-introduction
http://www.tableausoftware.com/data-extract-api

It's not hard, if you have trouble, feel free to ask

Comment: Gave some direction on SF API and Tableau API